# What could be the cause of the drop of the total reward when using DQN to solve the cart-pole environment?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn

I'm trying to use DQN to solve the cart-pole environment. I have 2 networks (target and behavior). Both of them have 3 hidden layers with 24 neurons, using the ReLU activation. The loss is MSE and the optimizer is Adam. I copy the weights of the behavior network to the target network every 15 backpropagation steps.

My agent learns. Below you can see the *total reward* and *running average* plots.

[image]

However, it has a lot of "drops". Usually, after a couple of perfect sequences, it just "kills" the running average with a couple of very short episodes. What may be the reason for this behavior?